# tkinter: inserting button in a text box next to text in each line dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Question:

I have a for loop which adds text to a text box.
I want a button to the extreme right after the text and before every iteration ends in the text box.

Also is it possible to assign some sort of tag that is the text before it to the button?
So for every iteration, the button calls a function and pass the text before it.

Expected Image:

[image]

Comment: I have a post that does something like this but with labels instead of a text box. Would that work for you?

Comment: I would prefer the Text box. Can Label do all the stuff that a Text box can do?

Comment: What is the reason for you needing the buttons? The problem with this idea is getting buttons to line up always where they should that is why I thought labels would work here better.

Comment: I have the text box that has text inserted dynamically using text.insert. As far as I know label can have text when you define them using Label(master, text="Rouge", fg="red"). I will have text in every line and tags associated to it.

Comment: For what reason thought do you need the buttons? This information will help me formulate a response/answer.

Comment: So the text box is the table of content, and there is another text box to the right with all the content. The button will pass the text in that line to a command which will hide that specific section/text from the text box to the right (content)

Comment: Ok. I will see what I can come up with for a text box. I still think labels would work better due to alignment issues but we will see what I can come up with.

Comment: Have you thought about just making the table of context a bunch of buttons? This can be auto generated and I do believe you can create some auto tagging as well thought it will take a little bit of work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183207/discussion-between-raj-mehta-and-mike-smt).

Comment: Likely down-voted due to no code attempt shown.

Comment: My understand is you can put _any_ tkinter widget in a `Text`—as is mentioned in this [reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-window.html). You might also be able to tag them (although I've never tried doing so).

Comment: @martineau that is cool. I didn't know text widget was capable of this. I will have to see if I can build an example from that link you provided.

Comment: @martineau: yes, you can embed any widget in a text widget.

Comment: @martineau: yes, I posted an answer that shows how to right-align something. The trick is to use a right-aligned tabstop.

Comment: @Bryan: Thanks, yes, I know—tried it. However Mike beat me to posting an answer. and just now saw the answer you posted which answers my own question about right-justifying them, so ditto for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

From the comment @martineau posted I was able to build something that will do mostly what it is you are asking. The problem is getting the buttons to align right. I think it might be better to align the buttons left but let me know what you think.

```
import tkinter as tk

list_of_file_data = [["Data set 1!", "This is the contents of data set 1.", True],
                     ["Data set 2!", "This is the contents of data set 2.", True],
                     ["Data set 3!", "This is the contents of data set 3.", True]]

class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("350x200")
        self.txt_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.txt_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.txt_box = tk.Text(self.txt_frame, width=40, height=15)
        self.txt_box.pack()
        self.update_textbox()

    def update_textbox(self):
        self.txt_box.delete(1.0, "end")
        for ndex, data_set in enumerate(list_of_file_data):
            if data_set[2] == True:
                self.txt_box.insert("end", "{}".format(data_set[0]))
                self.txt_box.window_create(self.txt_box.index("end"), window = tk.Button(self.txt_box, text="F", command=lambda x=ndex: self.toggle_data(x)))
                self.txt_box.insert("end", "\n")
                self.txt_box.insert("end", "    {}\n\n".format(data_set[1]))
            else:
                self.txt_box.insert("end", "{}".format(data_set[0]))
                self.txt_box.window_create(self.txt_box.index("end"), window = tk.Button(self.txt_box, text="F", command=lambda x=ndex: self.toggle_data(x)))
                self.txt_box.insert("end", "\n...\n")


    def toggle_data(self, ndex):
        if list_of_file_data[ndex][2] == True:
            list_of_file_data[ndex][2] = False
        else:
            list_of_file_data[ndex][2] = True
        self.update_textbox()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().mainloop()
```

The below images show buttons on the right side of the text but if you would prefer them to all be aligned left that is much easier than getting them aligned to the far right.

If you changed the `update_textbox()` method to this it will place the buttons on the left.

```
def update_textbox(self):
    self.txt_box.delete(1.0, "end")
    for ndex, data_set in enumerate(list_of_file_data):
        if data_set[2] == True:
            self.txt_box.window_create(self.txt_box.index("end"), window = tk.Button(self.txt_box, text="F", command=lambda x=ndex: self.toggle_data(x)))
            self.txt_box.insert("end", "{}".format(data_set[0]))
            self.txt_box.insert("end", "\n")
            self.txt_box.insert("end", "    {}\n\n".format(data_set[1]))
        else:
            self.txt_box.window_create(self.txt_box.index("end"), window = tk.Button(self.txt_box, text="F", command=lambda x=ndex: self.toggle_data(x)))
            self.txt_box.insert("end", "{}".format(data_set[0]))
            self.txt_box.insert("end", "\n...\n")
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

...

...

...

The below is my original example but I chose not to remove it as I believe it could be useful to some. This example will use buttons as the table of context and a tracking list to keep track of what can be displayed or not.

```
import tkinter as tk

list_of_file_data = [["Data set 1!", "This is the contents of data set 1.", True],
                     ["Data set 2!", "This is the contents of data set 2.", True],
                     ["Data set 3!", "This is the contents of data set 3.", True]]

class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("350x200")
        self.tbl_view = True
        self.tbl_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.tbl_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.txt_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.txt_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Button(self, text="Toggle Table of context", command=self.show_hide_tbl).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
        self.txt_box = tk.Text(self.txt_frame, width=30, height=10)
        self.txt_box.pack()
        self.update_textbox()

    def update_textbox(self):
        self.tbl_frame.destroy()
        self.tbl_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        if self.tbl_view == True:
            self.tbl_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.txt_box.delete(1.0, "end")
        for ndex, data_set in enumerate(list_of_file_data):
            tk.Button(self.tbl_frame, text=data_set[0], command=lambda x=ndex: self.toggle_data(x)).pack()
            if data_set[2] == True:
                self.txt_box.insert("end", "{}\n".format(data_set[0]))
                self.txt_box.insert("end", "    {}\n\n".format(data_set[1]))

    def toggle_data(self, ndex):
        if list_of_file_data[ndex][2] == True:
            list_of_file_data[ndex][2] = False
        else:
            list_of_file_data[ndex][2] = True
        self.update_textbox()

    def show_hide_tbl(self):
        if self.tbl_view == True:
            self.tbl_frame.grid_forget()
            self.tbl_view = False
        else:
            print("Else")
            self.tbl_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.tbl_view = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().mainloop()
```

Comment: @rajmehta I have updated me answer to provide buttons within a text box. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a tabstop to force something to be aligned to the right margin. The only trick is that you need to recompute the tabstop whenever the window is resized. You can do that by binding to the `<Configure>` event. When you place a window immediately after a tab and before the newline, it will be right-aligned.

You can associate a lambda function with the button to enable you to define data to be sent to the callback.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def reset_tabs(event):
    '''Add a tabstop at the right edge of the widget'''
    right_margin = event.width - 8
    if right_margin <= 0: return
    tabs = (right_margin, "right")
    event.widget.configure(tabs=tabs)

def callback(text):
    print("you clicked {}".format(text))

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
text.bind("<Configure>", reset_tabs)

for i in range(10):
    item = "this is item {}".format(i+1)
    text.insert("end", item + "\t\n")
    button = tk.Button(text, text="x", padx=2, pady=2,
                       cursor="left_ptr",
                       bd=1, highlightthickness=0,
                       command = lambda text=item: callback(text))
    text.window_create("end-2c", window=button)

root.mainloop()
```

The above code results in a window like this:

[image]